# In two unsorted arrays A and B such that all items of A belong to B (A ⊂ B), find the smallest item in B that doesn't occur in A in linear time?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

> In two unsorted arrays (say $A$ and $B$) such that all items of $A$ belong to $B$ ($A \subset B$), find the smallest item in $B$ that doesn't occur in $A$ in linear time.

No hashing or linear time sorting is allowed.

I can solve this question when $A$ and $B$ are sorted.
However, the question states $A$ and $B$ are unsorted, and I cannot think of a solution that solves this in O(n) time.

Comment: Why do you think it can be done in linear time?  Where did you encounter this question, and what was the source where you saw it?

Comment: Why would hashing not be allowed? Solving a problem with one hand tied behind your back is rather stupid, don't you think so?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that all elements in $A$ and $B$ are distinct (this assumption can be removed with some care), that elements possess a linear order, and that they can be compared in constant time.

Consider the following recursive algorithm:
if $|A|=0$, return the minimum in $B$ (in time $O(|B|)$).
Otherwise, find the median $x$ of the multiset obtained by unioning $A$ and $B$
and partition the elements of $A$ in  $A_{\le x}$ and $A_{> x} $  (resp. the elements of $B$ in  $B_{\le x}$ and $B_{> x} $) depending on whether they are at most $x$ or larger than $x$.
This requires time $O(|A|+|B|)$.

If $|A_{\le x}|=|B_{\le x}|$ then $A \subset B$ implies $A_{\le x}=B_{\le x}$ and you can recurse on $A_{> x} $ and $B_{> x}$.

If $|A_{\le x}| < |B_{\le x}|$ then the minimum element in $B \setminus A$ must be at most $x$ and hence it is in $B_{\le x} \setminus A_{\le x}$ and you can recurse on $A_{\le x}$ and $B_{\le x}$.

Let $n = |A| + |B|$. By the choice of $x$, the input size of the recursive call will be at most $\left\lceil \frac{|A|+|B|}{2} \right\rceil = \lceil n/2 \rceil$, showing that the algorithm eventually terminates (since $n \le 2$ implies $|A|=0$).

To bound the running time we notice that it is described by the recurrence
$
T(n) = T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + O(n)
$,
which has solution $T(n)=O(n)$.

Comment: It would seem to be fatal if A or B has two identical elements. First, A(<= x) can have more elements than B(<= x), and your conclusions from comparing the number of elements will fail. Of course a hash table can take care of that quite easily and remove duplicates.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are multisets (and $A \subset B$, counting multiplicities) the above approach works but the analysis of the time complexity breaks down. However we can easily restore it by partitioning $A$ and $B$ into $3$ sets each. The sets contain the elements smaller than, equal to, and larger than $x$.  If $A$ and $B$ represent sets but somehow can contain the same element more than once (and the multiplicity of an element doesn't matter), then I don't know how to solve the problem in linear time in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Reasoning:

- you are asked the *smallest* in $B$; this hints that the solution will be comparison-based.
- with an $O(n)$ budget, no comparison-based sort is possible; the best you can do with comparisons is to heapify !
- wonder what happens if you heapify the two arrays and compare them.

Notice that after a heapify operation, every array element is the smallest among the subtree of which it is a root. So when you compare the heaps formed from $A$ and $B$, the first discrepancy you will meet when scanning the elements will reveal the solution.

E.g.

$$A= [1,2,3,4,6],\\ B= [6,2,4,7,1,5,3]$$

heapify as

$$A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6],\\B=
[1, 2, 3, \color{green}7, 6, 5, 4].$$

Comment: I don't think this works $A = [1,3,2]$ and $B = [1,2,3,4]$ are both already heaps but the first discrepancy is at the second position.

Comment: @Steven: that's right. My tests did not show that. :-(